# SQL Server : error converting data type varchar to numeric unless I use REPLACE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that is using `varchar(255)` as a placeholder for storing many different data types. I am trying to do convert some of these values to `decimal` for a numerical comparison.

If I try to use the following function it will result in the error in the title

```
ISNUMERIC(Value + 'e0') = 1 and CONVERT(decimal (16,4), Value) < CONVERT(decimal (16,4),11)
```

I thought this was strange so I moved the `CONVERT` into the select statement to see if there were still some values the `ISNUMERIC` wasn't catching. There were not. The `CONVERT` above was able to successfully convert every single column with no errors.

```
select CONVERT(decimal (16,4), Value)
```

Next I tried wrapping the select in another select and moving the comparison to an outer query.  That didn't work either and also resulted in a lot of memory usage so I scrapped that idea.

One of my co-workers thought maybe there was one row of data that was causing an issue and even though the `CONVERT` on the select worked fine it was worth trying just to see.  We tried a `REPLACE` inside the `CONVERT`, as below:

```
ISNUMERIC(Value + 'e0') = 1 and CONVERT(decimal (16,4),REPLACE(Value, 'blah', '')) < CONVERT(decimal (16,4), 11)
```

...and somehow this worked. No matter what we type in the replace it works just fine. It clearly isn't replacing anything. I read that `REPLACE` will truncate very large data (8,000+ bytes) but this is a `varchar(255)` and so there isn't any large data in there to truncate.

I'm mostly curious as to why this works or if there is something else likely going on here and the `REPLACE` coincidentally worked? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Edit: Just to be clear, I am stuck with this database design. I cannot change it. I realize this is a terrible way to store data. Trust me.

Edit #2: I just found out that `TRY_CONVERT` will also work. My original question still stands I think. Even though I have two potential solutions I don't understand why it breaks.

Comment: "I have a database that is using varchar(255) as a placeholder for storing many different data types." This is not the right way to handle data at all. You should use the proper datatypes. When you use a varchar for everything you run all sorts of problems. Just don't do this to yourself.

Comment: Didn't design the database.  Can't change it.  I know how dumb it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, your expression is in the `where` clause:

```
where ISNUMERIC(Value + 'e0') = 1 and CONVERT(decimal (16,4), Value) < CONVERT(decimal (16,4),11)
```

SQL Server does *not* guarantee the order of valuation of expressions.  So, you don't know if the `convert()` is going first or the `isnumeric()`.  For such an expression in the `where` clause, all databases reserve the right to evaluate them in any order the optimization engine wants.

This is one case where using `case` in the `where` clause is beneficial.  `case` does have some guarantees on the order of valuation.  The following should work:

```
where (case when ISNUMERIC(Value + 'e0') = 1
            then CONVERT(decimal(16,4), Value)
       end) < CONVERT(decimal(16,4), 11)
```

The second convert is unnecessary clutter, in my opinion:

```
where (case when ISNUMERIC(Value + 'e0') = 1
            then CONVERT(decimal(16,4), Value)
       end) < 11
```

By the way, the use of `'e0'` is a clever way to just look for valid, non-exponential numbers.

Comment: I accounted for the undetermined order of expression evaluation with the inner/outer query though, at least I think I did.  I did the inner query which did the SELECT CONVERT with the WHERE ISNUMERIC and then selected from that and did the where on the outer and applied the numeric filter.  Shouldn't this have worked?

Comment: @Steven . . . Nope.  CTE's and subqueries don't affect the order of valuation.  Only the `case` is guaranteed to do that within a single query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - This issue can be really ugly on a JOIN when you think you are not joining to invalid data but it gets evaluated anyway because order of eval is not guaranteed and it is optimized to another thread.

Comment: Oh wow.  That is surprising.  I thought it would certainly evaluate the inner and then evaluate the outer.  Very useful information.  Do you know why the REPLACE fixes the issue though?  Does a REPLACE override the evaluation order somehow?

Comment: @Steven No, see [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) and [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63861/1186).

Comment: @Steven That may just be a coincidence with the plan you happen to get right now, but could change tomorrow. Don't rely on that as a fix.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Okay.  That is good information to know as well.  I didn't understand why the REPLACE was doing anything at all.  I ended up finding another solution which was to use TRY_CONVERT though I am not certain what the performance hit is yet.

Comment: @Gordon I don't like the `+'e0'` trick - what if the column already contains, say, `12e0`?

Comment: Also see [this ancient article](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.html) for the problems with `ISNUMERIC()`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Presumably, the purpose is to disallow those values, sticking with just numbers and an optional decimal point.  Easier than a bunch of `like` and `not like` statements.

Comment: @Gordon Right, but my point was, some users (maybe not *this* OP) actually want to use values like `12e0` that they have stored (and may not have any control over). It's not like it's easier to solve that problem with pattern matching either, just need to be careful not to eliminate potentially valid data through cleverness.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Unfortunately this is basically a read only connection to this database.  I cannot add a better, more complete, ISNUMERIC function.  Data isn't stored in exponent format and I couldn't think of a better way to guarantee numeric numbers.